# determine if Django model is marked for deletion

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

My example is very contrived, but hopefully it gets the point across.

Say I have two models like this:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

I want to add some code so that when a `Member` is deleted it gets recreated as a new entry (remember, very contrived!).  So I do this:

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Member)
def member_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.pk = None
    instance.save()
```

This works perfectly fine for when a `Member` is deleted.

The issue, though, is if a `Group` is deleted this same handler is called.  The `Member` is re-created with a reference to the `Group` and an `IntegrityError` is thrown when the final commit occurs.

Is there any way within the signal handler to determine that `Group` is being deleted?

What I've tried:

- The `sender` seems to always be `Member` regardless.
- I can't seem to find anything on `instance.group` to indicate a delete.  Even trying to do a `Group.objects.filter(id=instance.group_id).exists()` returns true.  It may be that the actual delete of the parent occurs after `post_delete` calls occur on the children, in which case what I'm trying to do is impossible.

Comment: What should be the end result when a group that has related members is deleted?

Comment: @knbk - The `Member` should just be deleted instead of moved to another `Group`.  So, the default that would occur without the signal handler.

Comment: What database are you using, and what is the isolation level of your transactions?

Comment: @knbk - Postgres and there's a transaction on each web request

Answer (score 0):

Try doing your job by a classmethod inside Member class and forget about signals.

```
@classmethod
def reinit(cls, instance):
    instance.delete()
    instance.save()
```

Comment: yes, but then you have to always remember to call the method.  The signal is called after a call to `.delete()`.

Comment: yes. you just have to remember to call reinit instead of delete.